# Print a MySQL table to a dynamic HTML table with PHP

Tags: php

I am teaching myself PHP and so far it has been going great. I am kinda stuck now and so in need of experts intervention here. I am trying to print a MySQL table to a dynamic HTML table with PHP. I want to display the column names and the rows based on the number of fields(colomns) and rows the query fetches. I have tried to iterate through the mysqli_fetch_row() for the rows and used a foreach on mysqli_fetch_fields(). But there is no output nor are there any errors. Here is a part of my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   $search=$_POST['name'];
   $conn=DBconnect();
   $result=SQLquery($conn, $search);

   if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
   {
      echo "<table id='tbl'><tr>";
      $field=$result->fetch_fields();
// output column names  
     foreach ($field as $col)
     {
        echo "<th>".$col->name."</th>";
     }
     echo "</tr>"

// output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_row()) 
     {
        echo "<tr>";

        for ($i=0;$i<=$result->field_count;$i++)
        {
           echo "<td>".$row[$i]."</td>";
        }

        echo "</tr>";
      }
     echo "</table>";

  }

else  
{
 echo "No data found";
}

}
```

Comment: Could you describe the SQLquery() function?

Comment: where is query and query execution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a semicolon missing at line number 16 of your code. Might be the reason for the issue. Also check if your DB connection, query and POST variables work fine. Other than that the rest of the code looks fine.

Comment: That was it! I had overlooked the missing semicolon. Thanks a lot. It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the next example with this class called Table:

```php
<?php

class Table {

    public function __construct ($name){  
      $this->data = null;
    }

    public function setData($data) {
      $this->data = $data;
    }

    function getCountColumns(){
      return (int) mysqli_num_fields($this->data);
    }

    function getCountRows(){
      return (int) mysqli_num_rows($this->data);
    }

    function render(){
      $columnsCount = $this->getCountColumns();
      $tableData = $this->data;
      $fields =  mysqli_fetch_fields($tableData);
      echo "<table class='table table-hover'>";
        echo "<thead>";
          echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($fields as $field) {
              echo "<th>";
                echo $field->name ;
              echo "</th>\n";
            }
          echo "</tr>\n";
        echo "</thead>\n";
        echo "<tbody>\n";
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tableData)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            for ($x=0; $x < $columnsCount; $x++) { 
              echo "<td >" . $row[$x] . "</td>\n";
            }
            echo "</tr>\n";
          }
        echo "</tbody>";
      echo "</table>";
    }

}
?>
```

and when you need it, include it into your html:

```html
<?php 
  include('Table.php');
  $table = new Table('myTable');
  $result=mysqli_query($sql_link, $query);
  $table->setData($result);
?>
<html>
  <body>
    $table->render();
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a little difference in `mysqli` method which following code is offered:

```
function createTable_from_sql_select_query($sql_link, $query) {

    $result=mysqli_query($sql_link, $query);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        echo "<table id='tbl'><tr>";

        $field = $result->fetch_fields();
        $fields = array();
        $j = 0;
        foreach ($field as $col)
        {
            echo "<th>".$col->name."</th>";
            array_push($fields, array(++$j, $col->name));
        }
        echo "</tr>";

        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            for ($i=0 ; $i < sizeof($fields) ; $i++)
            {
                $fieldname = $fields[$i][1];
                $filedvalue = $row[$fieldname];

                echo "<td>" . $filedvalue . "</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";


    }

}


createTable_from_sql_select_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM `Transactions`');
```